# Stop bootloader from timing out and choosing default partition?

Tags: ubuntu, bios, multi-boot, bootloader, timeout

I have Ubuntu 12.04 dual-booted with Windows 7, and I am using the Ubuntu boot loader. I'm sure many of you are familiar with the fact that after 10 seconds or so, it boots into the default partition. I would like to know if there is a way to disable this, so it will stay at the screen listing what partition you want until you choose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. If you're using GRUB (GRand Unified Bootloader)

1. Open the terminal and enter the following: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Find the line GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 and change the value (in seconds) to the one you desire (if you want to disable the timeout, use **-1**)
3. Save and close the file
4. In the terminal, enter the following: `sudo update-grub2`
5. Reboot and test

### 2. If you're using the newer BURG (Brand-new Universal loadeR from GRUB)

1. Open the terminal and enter the following: `sudo gedit /etc/default/burg`
2. Find the line GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 and change the value (in seconds) to the one you desire (you cannot completely disable the timeout though, so use a large number, like **600**)
3. Save and close the file
4. In the terminal, enter the following: `sudo update-burg`
5. Reboot and test

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. It's a shame the -1 won't work on BURG, but I have GRUB regardless

Answer (score 0):

As the `root` user open the file `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite text editor, locate the line containing `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` and change a numeric value to `-1` (minus one). 
Then save the changes and run the command `grub2-mkconfig`

All should be set.

Other possible values are:

`0` - do not wait at all;

`positive number` - amount of seconds to time out